# Maximum number of levels in a Binary Search Tree of Ascii Values?

Tags: c, ascii, binary-search-tree

I'm doing a pre-order traversal of a Binary Search Tree where each node contains a unique ASCII character (sorted based upon their decimal value).

I plan on printing the path to each node by adding a '0' to the path whenever I traverse left and adding '1' whenever I traverse right.  I plan to store this value in an array, but I don't know how to calculate the maximum size of the array.

If I have this correct, the maximum path size should be equal to the depth of a tree containing every ASCII character in a unique node.  How would I go about calculating the maximum depth?

Note: There are 255 total ASCII values.

Comment: See [max function c tree height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017566/max-function-c-tree-height)

Comment: Worst case, the tree will effectively be a linked list, and the depth will be the number of nodes...

Comment: if the height/depth is `h` then max node = 2^h+1. that's the max size of your array.

Comment: Note that ASCII is formally a 7-bit encoding with 128 values, not an 8-bit encoding.

Comment: There are 128 total [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Variants_and_derivations) values.

Answer (score -1):

Finding the maximum depth of a binary search tree can be done using recursion.

Recursion: Finding the maximum depth using recursion involves the idea of divide and conquer. Basically we divide the larger problem (finding the maximum depth of a tree) into two smaller problems (finding the maximum depth of left subtree and right subtree). After we find max(leftSubtree.depth, rightSubtree.depth), we add 1 to it to take into account the root level of the tree. The code would look something like this:

```
#Definition
def maxDepth(BSTNode root):

#Base Case
  if (root == null):
    return 0
#Find the maximum depth of left and right subtrees using recursion
  leftDepth = maxDepth(root.left)
  rightDepth = maxDepth(root.right)
  return max(left, right) + 1
```